# Why am I getting a syntax error in my function definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I'm trying to define a function, even the colour of the function (in my editor), doesn't turn bright. It's like I am missing something, but I don't know what. I've used the same `def` in another code and works.

```py
def calculate():
    try:
        f1=float(sum(k))
        f2=float(sum(v))
        final= f1 - f2
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Αποτέλεσμα", message =" ".join("Για την κατασκευή, χρειάζονται "+str(final)+"κυβικά τσιμέντου"
    except (tkinter.TclError, ZeroDivisionError):
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Λάθος Στοιχεία", message="Ελέγξτε πάλι τα στοιχεία που εισάγατε.")
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
except (tkinter.TclError, ZeroDivisionError):
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket on the previous line.

Comment: No, i am not, i have checked the whole code for brackets.

Comment: Yes you are. You're missing the closing bracket to the call to `showinfo` after "κυβικά τσιμέντου". You're missing the closing bracket for `join` too as well actually on the same line.

Comment: You are right. I'm over one hour stuck to this and i couldn't find what was wrong. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just a tip, if you have a non-nonsensical syntax error on a line, it usually means you're missing a closing brace/quote on the previous line. It's a very common error.

Comment: As to the miscolouring, make sure the file is saved with `.py` or `.pyw` extension.